# Condition inside a loop in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm trying to draw a chain of symbols by using a loop. I'm doing this way, but it always draw `x` circles...

```
1 to: x do: [
    (self lastWasSquare)
            ifTrue: [ self drawCircle]
            ifFalse: [ self drawSquare]
]
```

I also tried:

```
x timesRepeat: [ 
    (self lastWasSquare)
            ifTrue: [ self drawCircle]
            ifFalse: [ self drawSquare]
].
```

But still drawing circles. I also tryed to do it by adding a `:n |` variable to the loop and asking if even, but again, it's always executing the circle code.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: The code seems good to me, also `x timesRepeat:` is better when you don't need an index. Can you give us the code of the other three methods? Also you can try to put `self halt` as a first statement of the loop, or inside of the conditional blocks. This will act as a breakpoint, so you can check what is the result of `self lastWasSquare`, why it is like that and so on

Comment: Do `self drawCircle` and `self drawSquare` execute some side-effect which will cause `self lastWasSquare` to give a different result? Without knowing what the code for these selectors does, it's impossible to tell you why your code's not running as expected.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your call to `self lastWasSquare` keeps returning `true` so that your `#ifTrue:ifFalse:` keeps going into the block that calls `self drawCircle`. You can either:

1. Make sure that your `drawCircle` and `drawSquare` methods properly set your `lastWasSquare` instance variable (at least I'm assuming that's just a getter method).
2. Move the decision of whether the last item drawn was a circle or a square into a temporary variable.

The first way is better if you need the `lastWasSquare` value anywhere outside the method you're working on. The second way is better if it's the only place where you're drawing circles or squares (keep the scope as small as it needs to be) and could look something like this:

```
| lastWasSquare |
lastWasSquare := false.
x timesRepeat: [ 
    lastWasSquare
        ifTrue: [ self drawCircle ]
        ifFalse: [ self drawSquare ].
    lastWasSquare := lastWasSquare not
].
```

So you're continually toggling the `lastWasSquare` between `true` and `false`, and it will draw alternating shapes. (I'm assuming that's what you're trying to achieve when you say "draw a chain of symbols"...)

If neither of these apply, then, as Uko said in the comments, you'd need to post more of your code in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: @lurker eek, absolutely correct, thanks... edited. That's what I get for just typing it out without actually trying it in a workspace. ;-)